# PYTHON. Problemas con índice fuera de rango

Tags: python

tengo la siguiente tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y tengo el siguiente código donde comparo valores de las columnas Close y PSAR. Esa comparación genera una nueva columna, SituacionPSAR, según las condiciones que se presentan a continuación

```
for t in range(len(aapl.Close)):
  if aapl.Close[t]>aapl.PSAR[t]:
     aapl.SituacionPSAR[t] = "Bull"
  elif aapl.Close[t]<aapl.PSAR[t]:
     aapl.SituacionPSAR[t] = "Bear"
  else:
     aapl.SituacionPSAR[t] = "-"
```

El programa me arroja lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero alguno de los de acá me puedan ayudar con esto.

Muchas gracias.

Saludos!!!

Comment: te ayudamos pero... el código va como texto :)

Comment: Hola! Recuerda que el código y llas trazas de error se comparten como texto

Comment: ¿Qué es `aapl`?

Comment: Gracias por la información sobre el código. Ya está editado!!!
aapl es el nombre de la tabla.